# React Native Depth in a View

Tags: android, react-native, view, depth

I am stuck with a problem that I want the `opposite of elevation` in React native which would look similar like this
The second View which has some kind of ID in it. It is not elevated but has some depth in it. Can anyone help me to figure out its solution. Looks like shadow is coming inside not outside

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, I think it will help you =)

```js
shadowColor: '#000',
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
  shadowOpacity: 0.5,
  shadowRadius: 2,
  elevation: 2,
```

Comment: It's elevating the view but I want some ``depth`` inside the View

Comment: Looks like shadow is coming inside not outside.